# Xamarin forms CollectionView preselected not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

As title, I am using collection view and wanna make default select but it don't show properly.

below is my partial code:

this doesn't work, the first element didn't highlight

```
CategoryCollection.ItemsSource = _categoryRepository.Get(); // list of object
CategoryCollection.SelectedItem = _categoryRepository.Get()[0];
```

this can work, the first element was highlight(selected):

```
var temp = _categoryRepository.Get();
CategoryCollection.ItemsSource = temp ;
CategoryCollection.SelectedItem = temp[0];
```

I have tried override object equal function and operator ==, both don't work.

Comment: why are you setting ItemsSource twice?  That won't do anything useful.  Use the SelectedItem property to pre-select an item

Comment: Hi @Jason, I paste the wrong code, it should be 'SelectedItem'

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, above code would not work.

Comment: Are there any new updates?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you didn't assign the data to the same reference object.

`_categoryRepository.Get();` and `_categoryRepository.Get()[0];` maybe two different references.

When you set `CategoryCollection.ItemsSource = _categoryRepository.Get();` ,it's like

```
var list1 = _categoryRepository.Get();
CategoryCollection.ItemsSource = list1;
```

when you `CategoryCollection.SelectedItem = _categoryRepository.Get()[0];`,it's like

```
var list2 = _categoryRepository.Get();
CategoryCollection.SelectedItem = list2[0];
```

But list1 and list2 may not be the same reference object.So it couldn't recognize the selectitem.

However, when you use

```
var temp = _categoryRepository.Get();
CategoryCollection.ItemsSource = temp ;
CategoryCollection.SelectedItem = temp[0];
```

temp is always unique,so it could recognize the selectitem.

Comment: You are right, there a two different reference so CollectionView cannot regonize which should be hightlight, I had tried override object equal method also didn't work, I don't how Collection.SelectedItem implementation.

Comment: @user2986600  When you use `var temp = _categoryRepository.Get();`,it still couldn't work ?